# php dropdown list of folders and sub folders inside a directory

Tags: php, directory

i am looking to build a php function which will list all folders and sub-folders in a specific directory, but escape a certain directory folder/sub-folders in the list.

```
 $dir = "directory_to_scan_for_folders"
 $escape_folder = "folder_to_escape";

     function listFolders($dir) {
             $items = glob($dir . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
             for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
                 if (is_dir($items[$i])) {
                     $add = glob($items[$i] . '/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
                     $items = array_merge($items, $add);
                 }
             }
             return $items;
         }
```

i have been able to list all folders with the above function, but don't know how to escape a $escape_folder folder and its sub-folders from the list.

> Note: "escape_folder" mean a folder
>   which i don't want to show in list.

Comment: What do you mean by "escape folders"?  Do you mean that you want to avoid showing them in the list?

Comment: what do you mean by escape the folder?

Comment: By the way, You can use Directory iterator http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php . It can help You to produce cleaner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "escape folders" you mean a folder you don't want to see in the list, insert the following line immediately after `if (is_dir($items[$i])) {`:

```
if ($escape_folders == $items[$i]) continue;
```

But have a look at `foreach` instead of `for` and, as [petraszd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358308/petraszd) says, you probably want to look at [Directory iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) if you can. In that case, you'd use:

```
if ($escape_folders == $file->getBasename()) continue;
```

Comment: Thanks @mjac. Your single line of code has helped me to solved my problem.